# Show that $x^3+ax^2+b$ where $a>0$ does not have more than one root using Rolle's Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Show that $x^3+ax^2+b$ where $a>0$ does not have more than one root using Rolle's Theorem.

**My Attempt:** Let $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+b$ be the given cubic. Suppose that $f(x)$ has at least two distinct roots then call these roots $x_1,x_2.$ We then have that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ and so we apply the Rolle's Theorem on the interval $[x_1,x_2]$ and get that $f'(c)=0$ for some $c\in (x_1,x_2).$ Thus $c=0$ or $c=-2a/3. $ Clearly the roots must be of opposite sign or that they must be less than $0.$ I am unable to make further deductions. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If $b=0$ then we have the distinct roots $x=0$ and $x=-a$.

Comment: Well you are right! Thank you....

Comment: I think what you are trying to prove is that $x^3+ax^2+b$ doesn't have more than one *positive* root if $a\gt0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your work is fine. It seems to be a typo in the problem. The function should be $x^3+ax+b$. Then, the derivative has no zeros if $a>0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=1$ and $b=-2$ the plot of the function looks like this

[image]

So, there are roots.